# What is the most suitable hardware configuration for an intranet plone portal with a huge amount of data?

Tags: performance, disk-space, computer-building

I am using Plone 4, and I want to create a Plone site for the intranet. This site must be able to contain several hundred terabytes of data, including scanned PDF files, each of 50MB in average, and an archetype-based tree of document metadata records (about 15 fields per record), each for a folder of documents.

I have no idea about the hardware configuration that would be able to serve this site.

Comment: [stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plone) you probably get better help there

Comment: Well, I suppose, stackoverflow is for programming issues, and superuser is for hardware/administration questions. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'd think about a scalable architecture for the storage before wondering about the front-end. Perhaps something as Ceph/Amazon S3 for document storage, and a SQL database for referencing? This is not something to be undertaken lightly if you want some performance. I would contact a professional IT/application architect for this project.